# Explain answer to "Men in a state of agitation a very long time"

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

This crossword clue:

> "Men in a state of agitation a very long time (7)"

has the answer

> FOREVER

Please explain the "men" aspect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OR is one of those abbreviations which can mean "soldiers" in Britain (I think it's "other ranks"). A fever is a state of agitation, and OR inside FEVER makes the answer. The definition part is "a very long time", and if something takes forever it takes a very long time.

Comment: All very Housey-Housey old bean. "Other ranks" - rhymes with "Enemy tanks". Not a Daily Mail crossword then.

Comment: Y'know, this is why I wish American cryptic crosswords were easier to find. I find the idea of a cryptic crossword interesting, but I've lived in the US my whole life, and British crosswords invariably contain several references to things I've never heard of, like NAAFI.

Comment: @Tanner Yeah, I know what you mean. It's be super frustrating to spend time and energy trying to figure out a clue you were never going to get in the first place.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople:  there was a whole series of American cryptic puzzles, both crosswords and variety puzzles two or three decades ago.  They were published in 8 1/2 x 11 spiral bound books.  I found them on the puzzle shelf in the bookstore.  They seemed to be written by Will Shortz and friends, then they stopped showing up.  I don't know if you can find them now.